# how to change URL of JSP redirected from servlet

Tags: jsp, url, tomcat, servlets

I am developing a java web application using eclipse and tomcat server.
Application consists of JSPs and servlets.
I have deployed the application on tomcat server and I am redirecting to this application from the domain name.
When I goto "mydomain.co.uk" it redirects to the application with the URL "server:port/app_name".
I don't want people to see the serverIP and the port.
How can I show a different URL instead of "server:port/app_name".
Or is there anyway to make the URL constant for every JSP.
Application should work as it is working now but should show a different URL.

Comment: If you're not redirecting by yourself, then this has to be configured at mydomain.co.uk hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the protocol is http:// and the port number is not "80", then the port must be displayed in the URL (the same is true for https:// and port 443). If you don't want /app_name in your URL then you either have to re-name your webapp to ROOT (or ROOT.war if you are using a WAR file) or have a reverse proxy out front that can re-write the URLs. If you use a reverse proxy, you'll need to configure it and Tomcat properly so that both work to produce correct externally-facing URLs.

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution we used for a big project for government systems you use iframe tag

like this example

```
<tr>
     <td rowspan=2> &nbsp;</td>
    <td id="Page_layout_middle">
    <iframe id="content_frame" name="content_frame" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/showPage/Main.jsp" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </td>
    <td rowspan=2>&nbsp;</td>

</tr>
```

and have a menu to choose the screen you want the it will be included in the iframe and the url is still not change what so ever

```
http://servername:5100/appName/showPage/Main.jsp
```

it will look like page inside page!

and it make it faster so the images,logo,css,header and footer are loaded once only